# app crashes on startup after adding Ionic cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, phonegap-facebook-plugin

app getting crashed after adding `cordova-facebook4-plugin`

> I/System.out: Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: io.ionic.starter, PID: 16951
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
>           at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:171)
>           at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:97)
>           at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:86)
>           at com.getcapacitor.cordova.MockCordovaWebViewImpl.init(MockCordovaWebViewImpl.java:62)
>           at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:80)
>           at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:64)
>           at io.ionic.starter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16951 SIG: 9
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: I am getting the same error on a new project.

Comment: are you building it with android studio?

Comment: Are you building a capacitor project?